# Wrapping a writer in a reader in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a function in Go which generates XML and returns a reader for it.  However, the XML encoder seems to take a writer to write to and I'm not quite sure how to pipe the output of the writer to the reader I want to return.

I tried this:

```
func (i *Item) ToRss() io.Reader {                                                     
  reader, writer := io.Pipe()                                                             
  enc := xml.NewEncoder(writer)                                                           
  enc.Indent("  ", "   ")                                                                 
  enc.Encode(i)                                                                           
  return reader                                                                           
}
```

But when I run the following I get a fatal error:

```
  r := a.ToRss()
  buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
  buf.ReadFrom(r)
  s := buf.String()
  fmt.Println(s)
```

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Eventually I'd like to pipe the reader to the output of an HTTP request.  Should I just return a []byte?  Or is there a nice way to buffer the output so the client can use the reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipe does no internal buffering. It blocks on read or write until a corresponding write or read is called.

You should use a bytes.Buffer inside ToRss and return it as your reader:

```
func ToRss() io.Reader {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    io.WriteString(buf, "foo")
    return buf
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Aab3miciWF)

Alternatively you could start a new goroutine to write to the pipe and return it to be read from on the main goroutine. This method will avoid unnecessary buffering, but does introduce another goroutine.

```
func ToRss() io.Reader {
   reader, writer := io.Pipe()
   go func() {
      io.WriteString(writer, "foo")
      writer.Close()
   }()
   return reader
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/JDrM4i0q2x)

Comment: Thanks Craig! So before I was blocking in ToRss() and my main thread couldn't continue in order to read the data out.  Got it!  Thanks again.